# Looping through rows and then columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________
|id   |code  |code_status |code_due_date|code2  |code_status2 |code_due_date2|...|
|1    |ABCD  |A           |MMDDYYYY     |Null   |Null         |Null          |...|
|2    |Null  |Null        |Null         |Null   |Null         |Null          |...|
|3    |EFGH  |A           |MMDDYYYY     |ABCD   |B            |MMDDYYYY      |...|
|...  |...   |...         |...          |...    |...          |...           |...|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actual Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DATA (
    PRSN_UNIV_ID                            VARCHAR2(11),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_1                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_2                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_3                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_4                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_5                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_6                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_7                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_8                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_9                           VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_10                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_11                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_12                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_13                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_14                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_15                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_16                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_17                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_18                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_19                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_20                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_21                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_22                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_23                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_24                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_25                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_26                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_27                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_28                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_29                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_CD_30                          VARCHAR2(6),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_1                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_2                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_3                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_4                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_5                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_6                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_7                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_8                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_9                      VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_10                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_11                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_12                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_13                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_14                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_15                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_16                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_17                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_18                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_19                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_20                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_21                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_22                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_23                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_24                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_25                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_26                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_27                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_28                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_29                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_30                     VARCHAR2(1),
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_1                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_2                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_3                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_4                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_5                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_6                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_7                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_8                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_9                       DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_10                      DATE,   
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_11                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_12                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_13                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_14                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_15                      DATE,   
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_16                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_17                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_18                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_19                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_20                      DATE,   
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_21                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_22                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_23                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_24                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_25                      DATE,   
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_26                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_27                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_28                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_29                      DATE,
    CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_30                      DATE   
    )
```

I need to do something similar the the following pseudo code, but I do not know how to write it or if it even possible. I need to first loop through each row and test if a column in that row is equal to a code. If it is I want to take the status and due date of the same number and put it in the correct variable. There are about 30 different codes that I need to loop through to test for.

```
Declare variables
    variable_code_status
    variable_code_due_date
    variable_code_status2
    variable_code_due_date2
    variable_code_status3
    variable_code_due_date3

    ...

for each row
    for each column
        if column = code
            set variable_code_status = code_status
            set variable_code_due_date = code_due_date
        end if
        if column = code2
            set variable_code_status = code_status2
            set variable_code_due_date = code_due_date2
        end if
        if column - code3
            set variable_code_status = code_status3
            set variable_code_due_date = code_due_date3
        end if

        ...
    end for
end for

insert into table(
    variable_code_status
    variable_code_due_date
    variable_code_status2
    variable_code_due_date2
    variable_code_status3
    variable_code_due_date3

    ...);
```

I'm not sure if this will make sense to anyone or not.

Comment: This makes no sense... Can you post your *actual* table structure?  The table you provided has repeated column names...

Comment: A table cannot have multiple columns with the same name.  You can't have a table with multiple columns named `code` or `code_due_date`.

Comment: My bad. I have fixed that and added the actual structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this one:

```
declare
   id MY_DATA.PRSN_UNIV_ID%type;
   cd varchar2(6);
   stat varchar2(1);
   due date;
   cur sys_refcursor;
begin
   for i in 1..30 loop
      open cur for 
      'select PRSN_UNIV_ID, CHKL_ITM_CD_'||i||', CHKL_ITM_STAT_CD_'||i||', CHKL_ITM_DUE_DT_'||i||' from MY_DATA';
      loop
         fetch cur into id, cd, stat, due;
         exit when cur%notfound;
         if .... then --> put here all your conditions
            insert into ....
         end if;
      end loop; 
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're after, but it seems likely that rather than looping through, you'll probably be better off using `UNPIVOT` and a `JOIN` to a table with your codes:

```
WITH cte AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM  Table1 
            UNPIVOT (value FOR field IN ("code", "code_status", "code_due_date", "code2", "code_status2","code_due_date2"))
           )
SELECT a.*
FROM cte a
INNER JOIN codes b
 ON a.value = b."code_value"
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb141/8/0)

This gets you the ID, field, and value that matched your criteria. If you needed additional information from your base table, you could use these results to join back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SYS_REFCURSOR` and the `DBMS_SQL` package to dynamically address this requirement. The below procedure is a generic example of how to dynamically interact with a query, in this case it simply prints the results to the console. You could modify it to test the column descriptions at each iteration and perform some different operation. (This works in 11.2.0.3.0)

```
  PROCEDURE Output_Any_Query (
    pcRefCursor                 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS

    vnCursorNum         NUMBER;
    vnColCount          NUMBER;
    vtabDescriptions    DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    vsColumnValue       VARCHAR2(4000);

  BEGIN

    vnCursorNum := DBMS_SQL.to_cursor_number(pcRefCursor);      

    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(vnCursorNum, vnColCount, vtabDescriptions);

    --Print the column headers
    FOR i IN 1..vnColCount LOOP
      dbms_sql.define_column(vnCursorNum, i, vsColumnValue, 4000);
      dbms_output.put(RPAD(LPAD(vtabDescriptions(i).col_name,15),20)||'|');
    END LOOP;

    --End of line
    dbms_output.put_line('');

    --loop through the rows
    WHILE ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(vnCursorNum) > 0 ) LOOP 

      --loop across the columns
      FOR i IN 1 .. vnColCount LOOP 
        dbms_sql.column_value(vnCursorNum, i, vsColumnValue);
        dbms_output.put(RPAD(NVL(vsColumnValue,' '),20)||'|');
      END LOOP;

      --End of line   
      dbms_output.put_line('');

    END LOOP;

  END;
```